# How to detect backdoor origin - ssh brute forced

Tags: ssh, debian, apache-2.4

I've set up a little ARM server, running the latest version of armbian with kernel 4.11.6

I have Apache2:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Jul 18 2017 19:31:53
```

At home i'm using a cheap router Hawei HG8247H , with port forwarding active for port 80 and port 22 directing the incoming connections to the public IP, straight to the server inside the private network `192.168.1.114`

At first i've set up the root user with an too easy of a password that i suspect, was cracked by brute forcing ssh login...

After some thought over the subject i altered the password, switching to a stronger one. My doubt is, was the system compromised to the point where a mere password change of root isn't enough anymore?

I ran the `netstat -pan`:

[image: netstat -pan]

There's an abusive IP operating on my machine: 123.183.209.140; Probably serving as a spam zombie while i write this.

Also, ran nmap searching for vulnerabilities, yielding NOT VULNERABLE at least for the ones listed at the vulscan database to this day.

These high ports also seem suspicious. I feel uncanny with all the eerie movements on the server and the idea of a member of the internal network being compromised is scary as it is a trusted node of the internal network. Should somehow try to isolate the server in another separate network.

My doubt is, what is the next step to take from hereafter ?

Thank you for any advises.

Comment: Normally 1 side of the connection uses a high (ephemeral) port.  The IP you noted is connected, but possibly not logged in.  You could try killing the process and see what happens.

Comment: Screenshots don't look very well, use copy-paste and don't make screenshots (if it is possible, in your case it is).